# JAXB version attribute must be present error when generating Java classes fro WSDL

Tags: soap, jaxb, maven-2, jax-ws, xjc

I am trying to create client Java classes from a third-party WSDL. However when I run **mvn package** on the project, it displays the following error when using xjc to generate Java classes:

**[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ http://ultron.illovo.net:9704/analytics/saw.dll/wsdl/v6{2,257}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://ultron.illovo.net:9704/analytics/saw.dll/wsdl/v6; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 257; JAX
B version attribute must be present**

Here are extracts from the WSDL:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" elementFormDefault="qualified" jxb:version="1.0" targetNamespace="urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6" version="1.0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<jxb:schemaBindings>
<jxb:package name="oracle.bi.web.soap">
<jxb:javadoc/>
</jxb:package>
</jxb:schemaBindings>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
.
.
.
```

So the version is definitely specified in the  tag. Does the version also need to be specified in the bindings as shown below:

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
<jaxws:package name="oracle.bi.web.soap">
<jaxws:javadoc/>
</jaxws:package>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

and

```
<wsdl:operation name="import">
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
<jaxws:method name="_import">
<jaxws:javadoc>imports change log</jaxws:javadoc>
</jaxws:method>
</jaxws:bindings>
<wsdl:input message="sawsoap:importIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="sawsoap:importOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve? I'm the same exact problem with the WSDL generated from an Oracle service

Comment: @lincetto Hi, no I did not. However I managed to create the Java classes by running the following: 1. mvn eclipse:clean
2. mvn eclipse:eclipse
In eclipse:
1. refresh your project (click rmb and choose refresh)
(optionaly clean project)
Done.

Another approach is the run the following command. This is the simpler option:
mvn jaxb2:generate

Comment: @Neriyan Do you have any other solutions on this? I have the same problem, not using eclipse, and `mvn jax2b:generate` simply doesnt' help.